# Avoiding Downcasting

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How do you go about preventing downcasting when using interfaces? I have read some answers on stackoverflow that if you have to downcast then you most likely have a weak interface. How do you guys go about it then, and what's the proper way? I have a specific example, and I was wondering how I could properly avoid downcasting. In my example, I have an interface for passing data across, but the concrete implementation could contain unique attributes. In classes A and B I would need to downcast to DataType1 or DataType2 because they have different attributes types they could return.

```
struct IData
{
    virtual ~IData();
};

struct IAction
{
    virtual ~IAction();
    virtual void setup(IData& data) = 0;
};

class DataType1 : public IData
{
    int data1;
public:
    DataType1();
    int getData1();
};

class DataType2 : public IData
{
    std::string data2;
public:
    DataType2();
    std::string getData2();
};

class A : public IAction
{
public:
    A();
    void setup(IData& data) override;
}

class B : public IAction
{
public:
    B();
    void setup(IData& data) override;
}
```

Comment: Could you not just use a `template` for your data type?

Comment: `IData` should offer the required methods (which could either return the data, or return another interface that returns the data)

Comment: This would be an appropriate question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/  (design patterns)

Comment: @Tas I like your name. I need a universal way to setup classes A, and B. Their data can be drastically different.

Comment: If you need to know the exact type then polymorphism is an imperfect solution to the problem. Consider another approach. Or separate those parts that can be done polymorphically and those that can not.

Comment: I would ask the question **why** do you want these to have a common interface? They are clearly different types, why not just have overloaded functions that take differently typed data arguments?

Comment: @Galik I wanted them to have a common interface because they are being used by another component. Component C can have different types of Actions associated with it. Each Action has it's own set of logic, and needs to be setup when data comes in. In the end these Actions are ran by Component C. These Actions can also be dynamically changed. I was hoping to come up with a way to universally initialize them. Is there a pattern I can follow that helps separate something like this?

Comment: Initialization can *never* be 100% universal because *at the very least* you need to instantiate a specific type. So when you create the object you must know its full type. That is when you usually initialize it. Each different type can be initialized according to its own specific quirks. Only after that you can pass it to those parts of the system that do not need to know its exact type.

Comment: If you really want a universal initialization, then it *could* be done through a common interface if you are initializing from a common type, like a file or a text string. Something where each type receives the same input but parses it according to its own needs. That means `IData` would be a **fixed** type. Then you can avoid downcasting.

Comment: If interface A knows it will deal with data type 1, it should have setup interface based around data type 1.

Comment: @Galik Thanks you are the man.

Comment: @M.M when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Look at how other systems solve these problems: URIs, Database "connection strings", Monikers, RPC string bindings, CORBA names... e.g.: `"jdbc:dbtype://user@machine:port/dbname?isolation=serializable&ansi_nulls=on"` (adding to @Galik excellent comment)

Comment: Your types don't have a common interface, `IData` is just a virtual destructor which could be considered a mere technicality of using C++ rather than an interface. You could get away with passing them along as `shared_ptr<void>` and avoid the baseclass altogether. Maybe, a variant type would be more appropriate. Also, consider the Visitor Pattern, a.k.a. Double Dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, It's not a big issue to have a downcasting instruction in your code. This matter is valid as far as I know, and that's why C++ have dynamic_cast<> operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface shoulds define all method that you need to call on sub-classes as virtual method(better if are pure virtual methods).

In this case your interface can have 2 virtual method **getData** or in alternative if you compile with c++17 or more you can try to use ***std::any***.